# Elegant way for multiply tf.range()

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have a tensor of (BatchSize X 1) numbers, between 0 to 9,
e.g:

```
3
4
2
.
.
.
2
```

From each number i need to create a new tensor, starting with the number and descending until number - 9.
For example, for the number 3 i to create a tensor:

```
3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
```

This can be done using a single:

```
tf.range(3,3-9,1)
```

I need to do it for the whole tensor, to create a new tensor (following the example above):

```
3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7
```

One option is doing it in an iterative manner, but that requires me to hard-code the batch size into the loop, and i am trying to avoid that.

Any ideas for a good elegant solution will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an outer subtraction of the tensor with `tf.range(10)` by reshaping the tensor properly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant([3,4,2,2])

b = tf.reshape(a, (-1,1)) - tf.range(10)
b.eval()
#array([[ 3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6],
#       [ 4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5],
#       [ 2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7],
#       [ 2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for.